# Wix Cab error code 1

Tags: installation, wix

I am getting the following error in the log file:

```
 Action start 12:11:52: CreateIisConfigs.
MSI (s) (0C:7C) [12:11:52:731]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIFD80.tmp, Entrypoint: CreateIisConfigs
MSI (s) (0C:E8) [12:11:52:731]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (0C:E8) [12:11:52:733]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 10316 (0x284C).
MSI (s) (0C:F0) [12:11:52:751]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (0C:F0) [12:11:52:753]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server.
SFXCA: Extracting custom action to temporary directory: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSIFD80.tmp-\
SFXCA: Failed to extract to temporary directory. Cabinet error code 1.
CustomAction CreateIisConfigs returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 12:11:52: CreateIisConfigs. Return value 3.
Action ended 12:11:52: INSTALL. Return value 3.
```

I am using `<MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />` and WIX Toolset 3.10.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3):

You have a security/permission issue.
Check the line before this issue.

Also it could be related to exe file you are using in your CA.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for your input , but i dont run any exe's in my CA   , and also all i get is the General Wix Logging Stuff - I edited my Question so you can see it all

Comment: Try to run the msi as administrator.

Comment: Oh i always do that , and elevated cmd :)

Comment: As i can see you are running 32 bit "Hello, I'm your 32bit Impersonated custom action server." try to run the installer as 64 bit.

Comment: Also please add how you call your custom action code.

Comment: And check if Impersonate="no".

Comment: Yes i did.It had something to do with my business project.I had to delete it and recreate it..(the msi are getting stored in the resourses of a c# with a postback event.So something went wrong with that ,and end up with corrupted msis.

Comment: Ok, great to hear, please post an answer so people wont search the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i sort this issue out.In my specific case i have a post-build action that copies the msi file to the Resources folder of C# class library project.Somehow the msi got corrupted and thats why i had this `Cabinet error code 1` .After i manually copy paste the msi the error is gone.